# Where to call OnPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm

With WPF and MVVM, properties of the `ViewModel` are bound to UI elements. When a property changes, its set accessor calls `OnPropertyChanged` which in turn raises the `PropertyChanged` event of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

But it is possible to call `OnPropertyChanged` (with the property name as argument) from anywhere in the `ViewModel` (and then you can't use the `CallerMemberName` attribute).

Now I'd like to ask you: how do you handle such cases? Do you call `OnPropertyChanged` from other places than `property_set`? Or do you change your code such that you call `property_set`? Or other ideas?

Comment: FWIW I've struggled with this myself. I inevitably need to tell the framework that some VM property changed, even though it didn't, in order to get an ICommand's CanExecute method to trigger when something in my business model changed.

Comment: @RubberDuck You can force ICommand CanExecutes to be re-evaluated by calling CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()

Comment: @17of26 that class doesn't exist in UWP.

Answer (score 2):

Like everything else, it depends on the individual case.  Typically, your simple properties have a get and a set.  You call the set and it, in turn, raises the property change notification.

One common case where you need to manually raise property change notifications is with derived properties.  These don't usually have a set and can change based on modifications to other properties.

A contrived example:

```
public int ASquared => _a * _a;

public int A 
{
    get { return _a; }
    set 
    {
        if (_a == value)
            return;

        _a = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ASquared));
    }
}
private int _a;
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it showed an example of the `get` only derived properties you mentioned.

Comment: That's what ASquared is, although I botched the syntax.  Fixed now.

Comment: With the C#6 features (`nameof`), renaming of a property doesn't cause so many problems as before...

Answer (score 0):

I never call PropertyChanged directly, I use this very simple but extremely useful library:

https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties/blob/master/README.md

It is really a "formula engine" for MVVM that raises notifications from setters and for affected calculated readonly properties too (just like formulas in spreadsheets formulas react to change of source values)